# Problema devolución promesa

Tags: javascript, promesas

Hola mi problema es el siguiente. No logro devolver el usuario con el **resolve**, me devuelve null por mas que me lo encuentre. No se si es problema por el for y la promesa asincrona o porque. Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias

```js
_buscarPersonaDelTicket = function(ticketId){
    return new Promise (function(resolve,reject){
        try{
            var listaPersonas = dbTickets.PersonasConTickets();
            listaPersonas.then(function(listadoP){
                var encontrado=null;
                for(var i=0; (i<listadoP.length)&&(encontrado==null);i++){
                    console.log("i<listadoP.length : "+(i<listadoP.length));
                    console.log("encontrado==null : "+(encontrado==null));
                    var respuesta = dbTickets.buscarTicketEnPersona(listadoP[i],ticketId);
                    respuesta.then(function(usuario){
                        if(usuario!=null){
                            console.log("Usuario encontrado:"+usuario);
                            encontrado=usuario;
                        }
                    })
                }
                console.log(encontrado);
                resolve(encontrado);
            })
        }catch(error){
            //console.log(error);
            reject(error);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: es necesaria la segunda condición en el **for**?

Comment: Es que lo uso como segunda condicion de corte porque lo que hago (o intento) es buscar en una lista de arreglos un dato, y si lo encontro en el primer elemento que no siga buscando en todos.

Comment: Creo que esta mal entonces la estructura, por que veo que llamas el método `buscarTicketEnPersona` y eso retorna una nueva promesa, cuando encuentra el dato debería resolverse la función, no despues de que termine el ciclo